# org.jsoup.select.Selector$SelectorParseException: Could not parse query '': unexpected token at ''

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm building web scraper. I tried to improve this code:

```
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            Elements siteElements = document.select("div.grid__col.grid__col--20-80-80.b-products-wrap > ul > li:nth-child(" + i + ")");
            System.out.println(siteElements.select(" > div > div.b-products-list__desc-wrap > div > div.b-products-list__main-content > div.b-products-list__desc-prime > div.b-products-list__manufacturer-holder").select("a").first().text());
            System.out.println(siteElements.select(" > div > div.b-products-list__desc-wrap > div > div.b-products-list__main-content > div.b-products-list__desc-prime > div.b-products-list__title-holder > a").first().text());
            System.out.println(siteElements.select(" div.b-products-list__price-holder > a").first().text());
            System.out.println(siteElements.first().attr("data-ppc-id"));
        }
```

To this code (dont mind about last line, I know it is wrong after improval). So I took the part that is shared between 3 `sys.out`

```
 > div > div.b-products-list__desc-wrap > div > div.b-products-list__main-content >
```

and put it in `siteElements` variable (btw. is it good name for this variable?)

```
for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        Elements siteElements = document.select("div.grid__col.grid__col--20-80-80.b-products-wrap > ul > li:nth-child(" + i + ") > div > div.b-products-list__desc-wrap > div > div.b-products-list__main-content >");
        System.out.println(siteElements.select(" div.b-products-list__desc-prime > div.b-products-list__manufacturer-holder").select("a").first().text());
        System.out.println(siteElements.select(" div.b-products-list__desc-prime > div.b-products-list__title-holder > a").first().text());
        System.out.println(siteElements.select(" div.b-products-list__price-holder > a").first().text());
        //System.out.println(siteElements.first().attr("data-ppc-id"));
    }
```

but then I got exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.select.Selector$SelectorParseException: Could not parse query '': unexpected token at ''
    at org.jsoup.select.QueryParser.findElements(QueryParser.java:206)
    at org.jsoup.select.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:59)
    at org.jsoup.select.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:42)
    at org.jsoup.select.QueryParser.combinator(QueryParser.java:87)
    at org.jsoup.select.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:67)
    at org.jsoup.select.QueryParser.parse(QueryParser.java:42)
    at org.jsoup.select.Selector.select(Selector.java:91)
    at org.jsoup.nodes.Element.select(Element.java:363)
    at Main.main(Main.java:23)
```

What am I making wrong?
The site from which I **scrape** data: https://merlin.pl/bestseller/?option_80=10349074

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not end a selector with `>`, because this requires another selector to be valid. Just remove that or use `> *` or something similar and you won't get this exception. Maybe you have to adjust the selector a bit further to get elements you want.